# Not able to get Access Token from postman tool

Tags: postman, identityserver4

I was trying to fetch the access token from my Identity server hosted in my local/remote. it showing error as request body should have client secret/client assertion.

Comment: i am passing client secret already from postman tool

Comment: In IdentityServer Log: this is logged " Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'invalid_client', error_description: 'AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'."

Comment: Do i need to configure Client Secrets in Azure AD Application ?

Comment: Share your request sample

Comment: please include the whole request (body **and** headers) as shown in PostMan.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full tutorial I wrote. Hope this helps.

 https://medium.com/@rotter.axel/automatically-sign-in-to-identity-server-4-with-postman-and-test-net-core-controller-methods-bc5d8feb199e

Comment: Thanks @axelrotter, will visit the page.

Comment: If it is useful to you. please mark this as an answer.